# GCC, std::ctype specialisation & streams

Tags: c++, unicode, locale, iostream, facet

I've written my own specialisation of each virtual member function of `std::ctype<char16_t>`, so that this now works:

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include "char16_facets.h"  // Header containing my ctype specialisation
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// Implemented elsewhere using iconv
std::string Convert(std::basic_string<char16_t>);

int main() {
    std::basic_string<char16_t> s("Hello, world.");
    std::basic_stringstream<char16_t> ss(s);
    ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new std::ctype<char16_t>()));
    std::basic_string<char16_t> t;
    ss >> t;
    std::cout << Convert(t) << " ";
    ss >> t;
    std::cout << Convert(t) << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to make streams use the new ctype specialisation by default, so I don't have to `imbue` each stream with a new locale?

I haven't written a new class, just provided

```
template<>
inline bool std::ctype<char16_t>::do_is (std::ctype_base::mask m, char16_t c) const {
```

etc.  I'd sort of hoped it would be picked up automatically, so long as it was declared before I `#include <sstream>` but it isn't.

Most of the work for the above was done using G++ and libstdc++ 4.8, but I get the same result with them built from SVN trunk.

**Edit - Update** This question originally asked about how to get number extraction working.  However, given a stream imbued with correct `ctype` and `numpunct` implementations, then no specialisation of `num_get` is necessary; simply

```
ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), new std::num_get<char16_t>()));
```

and it will work, with either gcc version.

Again, is there some way to get the streams to pick this up automatically, rather than having to imbue every stream with it?

Comment: `std::locale::global(std::locale(), new std::ctype<char16_t>());`

Comment: Just so - thanks.  A further question - does this replace the existing ctype<char> facet of the global locale?  Or does it mean that the global locale will have both ctype facets and will use the one appropriate to the type of the stream?  I'm guessing the latter, because it works, but I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: It replaces the `std::ctype` facet in the global locale. I can't explain why it works as you just described though.

Comment: Does it?  According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale, the 'classic' locale always contains at least ctype<char> and ctype<wchar_t>; why couldn't you add another ctype on top of that?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. Your `std::ctype<char16_t>` specialization introduces a new _facet family_ and thus does not replace the `std::ctype<char>` or `std::ctype<wchar_t>` facets because they all have different _facet identifications_. So your code will work because the character type of the stream is `char16_t`, and so it will use the `std::ctype<char16_t>` facet you specialized and imbued into the global locale.

Comment: Great.  If you'd like to write that up into an answer, I'll accept it; otherwise, I'll write it up myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::locale::global()`:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(std::locale(), new std::ctype<char16_t>()));
```

Comment: That's better. Answers go as _answers_!